# css getting an element using a ancestor

Tags: css, sharepoint

I have this html

```
<div id="NBSAreaDirectorySearch">
    <div class="ms-webpart-chrome ms-webpart-chrome-fullWidth ">
        <div class="ms-WPBody " id="WebPartWPQ2" allowdelete="false" onlyformepart="true" width="100%" haspers="true" webpartid="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000">
            <div style="display: none;"></div>
            <div id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_g_2ea1c174_49f1_467b_89ff_d32d6c945151_csr" componentid="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_g_2ea1c174_49f1_467b_89ff_d32d6c945151_csr">
                <div class="ms-floatLeft" id="SearchBox" name="Control">
                    <div class="ms-srch-sbLarge ms-srch-sb-border nbs-landingAreaDirectory-srchBoxDiv" id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_g_2ea1c174_49f1_467b_89ff_d32d6c945151_csr_sboxdiv">
                        <input title="Search within the Branch Directory">
                        <a title="Search">
                            <img id="searchImg">
                        </a>
                        <div>
                            <div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="SearchOptions">
                </div>
            </div </div>
            <div class="ms-clear">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

everything below the `NBSAreaDirectorySearch` is auto generated, so the id's could be different, apart from the `searchImg`. I want to change the css of the `searchImg` going via the `nbsareadirectorysearch` as there is another `searchImg` on the page to.
SharePoint site, so there is a searchimg in the master page and one in the page layout. unfortunately I can't change the id as its autogenerated

Comment: `#NBSAreaDirectorySearch #searchImg{ }` doesnt work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just be able to target the specific image using

```
#NBSAreaDirectorySearch #searchImg {
    border: red 1px solid;
}
```

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t3tvq1m3/) using exactly what you posted. I've used a placeholder image to highlight the red border style that is applied.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the structure is always the same and the only things that change are the IDs.

```
#NBSAreaDirectorySearch a[title=Search] img  {
yourstyleshere;
}
```